# GitLab Local Deployment using a lot of disk space without any repos

Tags: server, gitlab, storage, prometheus, grafana

I've just recently deployed GitLab CE in a personal server to play around with. I haven't done anything with it as of yet, just added a user for myself so I'm not sitting around in the root, yet I'm watching the storage usage of the container slowly increase over time.

When I got Prometheus set up to track my containers, GitLab was already sitting at 14MB, then over the course of a day it increased to 125MB linearly, so about 111MB per day of storage.

Compared to Prometheus tracking all metrics on my system and in each container, I'm seeing about 130KB of storage increase per day. I'm assuming at idle, GitLab shouldn't be saving a lot of information, especially when there aren't any projects or repositories.

To try and curb this increase, I've stopped all of the cronjobs that are running, and I do think I see the graph leveling out, however it's not been completed stopped. I also don't know how viable it is to run GitLab without any of the cronjobs running as some of them seemed important for repo management (`ci_pipelines_expire_artifacts_worker`, `ci_schedule_delete_objects_worker`, `image_ttl_group_policy_worker`, etc)

My question is why is the data usage increasing so fast? What information is being stored? Is there a chance that this information is rolling and it'll stop increasing once it reaches some threshold?

Comment: Here's a screenshot of the graph I'm seeing:
[Screenshot (Pastboard)](https://pasteboard.co/3C3REUVoU28M.png)

Comment: What have you done, to locate the problem? Have you checked filesystem for file/folder that constantly increases? Also, are you sure it's containers fault? Is there access to storage attached to that container / does storage increase when containeris stopped??

Comment: I will stop the container now to see. After turning off the cronjobs, I do see the speed that the storage is used has halved, but still very fast for not doing anything. I deleted the container and volumes and recreated it once and saw the graph drop to zero on the new container (same name), so I'm pretty sure it is due to gitlab. The volumes used by the container are only accessed by the one container. I have not found any particular file that has a lot of data... I'll search now

Comment: After stopping the container for a day and starting it back up, the data usage started right back where it left off and continued growing. I did a `du -a | sort -nr | head` from within the container and the root of the filesystem only reports about 4.2MB used. I ran a `docker system df` and see that containers in general are using 3.046MB, which is somehow less? I have a Minecraft server that Prometheus reports is using 2.87MB, as well, so I'm not really sure what to believe.

Comment: The query I'm using in Grafana is `sum(container_fs_usage_bytes{instance=~"$host",name=~".+"}) by (name)`

Comment: Addendum to my prior comment, containers are using 3.046MB, however Local Volumes are using 2.683GB, and that's where the gitlab data is stored.